# Inconveniente al querer activar el entorno de trabajo virtual dentro de Python haciendo uso del editor Visual Studio Code:

Tags: python, django, vscode

Cordial saludo necesito solicitarles a ustedes la colaboración que me puedan brindar con el siguiente  inconveniente referente a la activación del entorno virtual dentro de Python haciendo uso de Visual Studio Code, pues en la terminal de esta herramienta pongo lo siguiente:
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql> venv\Scripts\activate.bat

En donde PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql> es la ruta de mi aplicación y
venv\Scripts\activate.bat es la ruta del archivo (activate.bat) que tiene como objeto activar el entorno virtual pero desafortunadamente no se me activa dicho entorno pues no aparece
(venv) C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql>
sino que me sigue apareciendo   PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql>
vale mencionar que estoy siguiendo las indicaciones que se muestran en el tiempo 4:02 del siguiente enlace :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zNZ1lK6RTA&t=205s

Muchas gracias por cualquier observación que me puedan brindar

Comment: Saludos. Podrías indicar el nombre de tu entorno virtual?

Comment: El nombre del entono virtual es venv y estoy buscando activar el entorno virtual con el archivo active.bat

Comment: Usa `activate.ps1` en powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Ahí está el error, no deberías usar el .bat. Con solo poner activate es suficiente.

Otra cosa, Windows te bloquea el uso de scripts, por lo que hay que desactivar eso en powershell

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).